# Error in importing a python file

Tags: python, import, module

I've written a python file and am trying to import it but it's not recognized.
The file was saved as gentleboost_c_class.c in `C:\User\apps\My documents`. 
I tried to import it like this:

```
import gentleboost_c_class as gbc
```

But I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'gentleboost_c_class' is not defined
```

`gentleboost_c_class.py` begins like this:

```
from sklearn.externals.six.moves import zip
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
class GentleBoostC:

.....
```

It compiles fine. 
Both files are in the same folder.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is python going to know where gentleboost_c_class is located?

Comment: Where is the file that you're importing from located? (i.e. not `gentleboost_c_class.py` but the other file)

Comment: You're getting a **`NameError`**, not an `ImportError`. Seems to me that you import your module as `gbc`, but later try to refer to it as `gentleboost_c_class`.

Comment: Both files the one I'm importing into, and the one I'm importing, are in the same folder, as I just mentioned at the end of the question.

Comment: @LukasGraf you're right. I called it like this: `gentlebooster = gentle_boost_c()`.
But now, when I'm calling it like this: `gentlebooster = gbc()`, I'm getting this error:
` gentlebooster = gbc() 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: @user961627 that's a different problem then. As the error message states, a module object is not callable, but you're trying to do that with `gbc()`. What are you actually trying to do? Instanciate the class `GentleBoostC`? Then it would be `gbc.GentleBoostC()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a **`NameError`**, not an `ImportError`.

So it seems to me that you import your module as `gbc`, but later try to refer to it as `gentleboost_c_class`.

If you import the module with

```
import gentleboost_c_class as gbc
```

that means it will be available under the global name `gbc`, but not as `gentleboost_c_class`.